# TCPDF MultiCell ishtml error when transform links, only first its clikable

Tags: php, tcpdf

I'm creating a pdf from a parsed markdown. I've already check de parsed html et cette ok. When I utlise the multicell function to creates the pdf from html only the first link it's clickable.

My MultiCell function:

```
$this->MultiCell($this->lengthComment,5,nl2br($comment_parsed),$this->lineBorder,'L',0,1,'','',true,0,$ishtml=true); //ishtml = true
```

My comment parsed transformation:

```
$comment = $line_array['body'];
require_once('modules/bnsQuotes/Parsedown.php');
$parsedown = new Parsedown();
$comment_parsed = $parsedown->text($comment);
```

If I use ishtml = false text it's display like html tags but all links are clickable, if I use ishtml = true the links are display like normal blue link but only first link it's clikable.

Comment: Why don't use `writeHTMLCELL`  / `writeHTML` ?

Comment: je vais voir merci

Comment: I've check it and none works every time same result, three off theme give me the same result

Comment: Why do you use this plugin when instead you can directly use writeHTML

Comment: I don't use a plugin, I only have a class to parse the Markdown into HTML after I've used MultiCell, writeHTMLCELL and writeHTML, but none it's working

Comment: if you use `$comment` directly work?

Comment: yes in browser, if i open pdf in app not